# My javascript code doesn't work in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript

It was brought to my attention that my webpage loads fine in chrome, but my javascript effect only works in Chrome..

It is a fading scroll effect, meaning that the first div is lit up, while the divs below it are dark and when i scroll down the top div gets dark and the one in the middle lights up and so forth.

Could someone please help me figure out why it doesn't work?

Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  if ($(".pathe")[0]) {
    if (wScroll > $('.ribfactory a').offset().top) {
      $('.ribfactory').addClass('filter');
      $('.ribfactory').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.pathe').addClass('invertedfilter');
    } else {
      $('.ribfactory').removeClass('filter');
      $('.ribfactory').addClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.pathe').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.pathe').addClass('filter');
    }

    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (wScroll > $('.pathe a').offset().top) {
      $('.pathe').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.pathe').addClass('filter');
      $('.boozy').addClass('invertedfilter');
    } else {
      $('.boozy').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.boozy').addClass('filter');
    }
  } else if ($(".muesli")[0]) {
    if (wScroll > $('.muesli a').offset().top) {
      $('.muesli').addClass('filter');
      $('.muesli').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.ice').addClass('invertedfilter');
    } else {
      $('.muesli').removeClass('filter');
      $('.muesli').addClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.ice').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.ice').addClass('filter');
    }

    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (wScroll > $('.ice a').offset().top) {
      $('.ice').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.ice').addClass('filter');
      $('.adventure').addClass('invertedfilter');
    } else {
      $('.adventure').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.adventure').addClass('filter');
    }
  } else if ($(".polymed")[0]) {
    if (wScroll > $('.polymed a').offset().top) {
      $('.polymed').addClass('filter');
      $('.polymed').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.safety').addClass('invertedfilter');
    } else {
      $('.polymed').removeClass('filter');
      $('.polymed').addClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.safety').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.safety').addClass('filter');
    }
  } else if ($(".tailoreliza")[0]) {
    if (wScroll > $('.ribfactory a').offset().top) {
      $('.ribfactory').addClass('filter');
      $('.ribfactory').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.tailorbnn').addClass('invertedfilter');
    } else {
      $('.ribfactory').removeClass('filter');
      $('.ribfactory').addClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.tailorbnn').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.tailorbnn').addClass('filter');
    }

    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (wScroll > $('.tailorbnn a').offset().top) {
      $('.tailorbnn').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.tailorbnn').addClass('filter');
      $('.tailoreliza').addClass('invertedfilter');
    } else {
      $('.tailoreliza').removeClass('invertedfilter');
      $('.tailoreliza').addClass('filter');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML also and make a snippet?

Comment: without seeing the CSS (which obviously is important as you are adding/removing classes everywhere) then the answer is ... not a chance that anyone can help - my guess is that the CSS is full of -webkit- prefixed stuff ... but, that's a guess

Comment: i want to know if you have added jQuery to your page. for debug check console for error.